# Внешняя база данных sqlite для ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

Как лучше реализовать работу приложения с внешней базой данных sqlite, то есть файл базы данных скачивается с интернета и в приложении считывается, регулярно обновляется через интернет. Какую библиотеку лучше использовать для работы с файлом базы данных sqlite, я раньше использовал fmdb но это что-то устаревшее как я понял.

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробывать SQLite как одну из самых популярных библиотек: https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift